# Invalid Column Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I generated my model classes with Entity Framework Code First.
However , it shows an exception whenever I call `db.Model.ToList()`;
The exception : `{"Invalid column name 'rapportAnomalie_code_rapport'."}`

I don't have such a column and Idk where it came from .
My Db tables :

**refAnomalie.sql** :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[refAnomalie] (
[code_anomalie]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[libelle_anomalie] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[score_anomalie]   INT            NOT NULL,
[classe_anomalie]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.refAnomalie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([code_anomalie] ASC)
);
```

**rapportAnomalie.sql** :

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rapportAnomalie] (
[code_rapport] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[date_rapport] DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[etat]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[code_agence]  INT           NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.rapportAnomalie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([code_rapport]    ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.rapportAnomalie_dbo.agence_code_agence] FOREIGN KEY    ([code_agence]) REFERENCES [dbo].[agence] ([code_agence]) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );


 GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_code_agence]
  ON [dbo].[rapportAnomalie]([code_agence] ASC);
```

**refAnomalie.cs :**

```
 [Table("refAnomalie")]
    public partial class refAnomalie
    {
        [Key]
        public int code_anomalie { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string libelle_anomalie { get; set; }

        public int score_anomalie { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string classe_anomalie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**rapportAnomalie.cs :**

```
 [Table("rapportAnomalie")]
    public partial class rapportAnomalie
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public rapportAnomalie()
        {
            ligneRapportAnomalie = new HashSet<ligneRapportAnomalie>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int code_rapport { get; set; }

        public DateTime date_rapport { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string etat { get; set; }

        public int code_agence { get; set; }

        public virtual agence agence { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ligneRapportAnomalie> ligneRapportAnomalie { get; set; }


        public List<refAnomalie> listeRefAnomalie { get; set; }
        public List<ligneRapportAnomalie> listeLigneRapportAnomalie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have looked for some solutions on the internet such as adding `Database.SetInitializer<InspectionBanqueContext>(null);` or deleting Migration table from the sql server database but non worked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a table called code_rapport in your database? In that case there's probably a missmatch with the **KEY** code_rapport and the table

Comment: No I don't have any table with that name.

Answer (score 0):

There are strategies for set initializers - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/794187/Various-Strategies-to-Initialize-Database-in-Entit

`Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestContext>());` - drop always

`Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new  CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestContext>())`; - creates only if not exists. So it database there then it will not change it - use update database if your database has data which you need - http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

So you need to run the powershell commands using package manager console for updating your context

Comment: Do you require data to be persisted. Else dropcreate will create fresh one and you should not be encountering issues

Comment: Yes, data should be persisted always. However, I tried Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new  DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>()); anyways but still the same problem. The problem is I don't know why  EF generates rapportAnomalie_code_rapport which doesn't exist in my database